# how to fix "/usr/bin/ld: warning: liblber-2.4.so.2, needed by //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4, not found" in c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am running my c++ code with some image processing library and I am getting warning issue

> /usr/bin/ld: warning: liblber-2.4.so.2, needed by //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4, not found

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following steps , it may be useful for your problem :

- `apt download libcurl3`
- `dpkg --extract libcurl3_7.58.0-2 ...`

  > you must extract downloaded package (according which type of package is downloaded)
- `cp curl/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4* ...`

  > Copy all `.so` files from `curl/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` to your requirement path

Answer (score 0):

liblber is part of libldap:

`sudo apt install libldap2-dev`

or:

`sudo apt install libldap-2.4-2`